# How can I send a file created by javascript, to server and then handle it by django, for emailing?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

My javascript code:

```
function PrepareEmailPrescription() {
    doc = PreparePrescriptionPDF()
    var pdf = doc.output();   
    var fd = new FormData();    
    fd.append( 'file', pdf );
    $.ajax({
        url: `/clinic/${cliniclabel}/prescription/sendemail/patient/${patient_id}`,
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        }
    });  
}
```

Here, PreparePrescriptionPDF is a function which generated a pdf file with pdfjs.

On the django server, I have:

```
def SendPrescriptionbyMail(request, cliniclabel, patient_id):
    # print(request.body)
    print(request.FILES)
    print(request.FILES['file'])
    return HttpResponse('Successfully sent email')
```

I am getting the following response from django:

```
[14/Nov/2018 15:59:18] "GET /clinic/medicines HTTP/1.1" 200 8389
<MultiValueDict: {}>
2018-11-14 15:59:22,344 django.request ERROR    Internal Server Error: /clinic/madhav/prescription/sendemail/patient/18
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 77, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/clinic/views.py", line 4911, in SendPrescriptionbyMail
    print(request.FILES['file'])
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 79, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'file'
```

However if my javascript code becomes:

```
function PrepareEmailPrescription() {
    doc = PreparePrescriptionPDF()
    var pdf = new Blob(['abc123'], {type: 'text/plain'});
    var fd = new FormData();    
    fd.append( 'file', pdf );
    $.ajax({
        url: `/clinic/${cliniclabel}/prescription/sendemail/patient/${patient_id}`,
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        }
    });  
}
```

I get:

```
[14/Nov/2018 15:57:05] "GET /clinic/medicines HTTP/1.1" 200 8389
<MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: blob (text/plain)>]}>
2018-11-14 15:57:10,500 django.request ERROR    Internal Server Error: /clinic/madhav/prescription/sendemail/patient/18
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 105, in process_response
    if response.status_code == 404:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

What's the proper way to do this? How can I send a on-the-fly-created pdf file to my django server for emailing as an attachment?

Comment: What is the type of doc.output() ? Console logging this would be useful information.

Comment: you get an error in `django` code either way. Are you sure you do not miss something else?